# One sample - why can't $\sigma^2=0$?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

The assumption is that

$Y_1,...,Y_n$ are independent and $Y_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. The unknown parameters are $(\mu,\sigma^2) \in \mathbb R \times(0,\infty) $.

Question: Why can't variance be 0? meaning: $\sigma^2 =0$.

Kind regards,

Comment: Look at the PDF of a normal distribution. Do you see any issues with $\sigma=0$, a fraction, perhaps?

Comment: Oh, then it will be just get a histogram with one bar. What will interpretation of this be? A distribution with only one possible value? So a binomial distribution?

Comment: If the variance was 0, then every $Y_i$ would just be equal to $\mu$, so there would be no need to comment on the distribution anyway.

Comment: So every number $y_i$ which comes of from $Y_i$ is the same, right? Does this trivial distribution not have a name? Maybe the trivial distribution?

Comment: The 'normal distribution with $\sigma^2 = 0$' sometimes refers to a distribution with point mass $1$ on $\mu$ and is called a 'degenerate normal'. It differs completely from 'real' normal distributions with $\sigma^2 > 0$ as it does not have most of it's 'pretty' properties.

Comment: Alright. Is it possible to simulate in R?

Comment: The degenerate one?

Comment: Not sure you've fully grasped the point - the $y_i$ are all equal to the same number, $\mu$.  All you need is an assignment;`y <- rep(mu,n)` in R creates a vector of length `n` with all values equal to `mu`.

Comment: Alright. Another thing: Just because alle the $y_i$ is the same it does not mean that all the $Y_i$ is the same?

Comment: All $Y_i$ (Random variables) have that same normal distribution, so it doesn’t matter what the $y_i$ (realizations of the random variables, so numbers, draws from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ if that works for you), are. The $Y_i$ al have the same distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in your question that the distributional form is an assumption (and therefore so is the allowable set of parameter values), so it is really up to you what assumption you wish to make.  It is possible to extend the family of normal distributions to include the case where $\sigma=0$, and in this case the distribution degenerates to a point-mass distribution on $\mu$.$^\dagger$  In answer to your follow up question in the comments, yes, it is possible to simulate this in `R`, and the standard commands for the `norm` distribution accomodate this case.

```
#Example of simulations from normal distribution with zero variance
mu    <- 10;
sigma <- 0;
rnorm(20, mu, sigma);

[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

There is no particular reason that you have to exclude the possibility that $\sigma = 0$ from your analysis.  Obviously if you exclude this case by assumption, then by assumption this outcome cannot hold.  However, you can certainly include that case as an allowable distribution in the analysis, in which case you are looking at a broader version of the family of normal distributions that includes this point-mass distribution.

---

$^\dagger$ It is a matter of convention whether or not the point-mass distribution is considered part of the family of normal distributions.  Most texts exclude it so as to focus on the continuous distributions, and retain certain general properties that don't hold with the inclusion of this case.  Nevertheless, it certainly would not be unreasonable to include it.  Whether or not you consider the point-mass distribution to be part of the "family of normal distributions", it is useful to include it in analysis for practical purposes, to ensure that the parameter space is closed.  Having a closed parameter space is useful for various reasons, including the fact that it ensures that in the case where you have observed data $y_1=\cdots=y_n$, your estimator $\hat{\sigma} = 0$ is in the parameter space.

Comment: Reminds me of the Dilbert 9999 cartoon from 10/25/2001.

Answer (score 3):

In normal distribution

$$E(Y_i -\mu)^2=\sigma^2$$

so if $\sigma^2\rightarrow 0^+$ so $$E(Y_i -\mu)^2\rightarrow 0^+$$ in hence

$$P(Y_i=\mu) \rightarrow 1$$ so $Y_i$ are degenerate random variable in $\mu$. When variance equal 0 so the distribution is a degenerate  one.

```
 R code, simulation
 sigma<-c(.1,.01,.001,.0001,.00001)
 n<-10000
 mat<-matrix(0,ncol=n,nrow=length(sigma))
 for( i in 1:length(sigma)){
 set.seed(i)
 mat[i,]<-rnorm(n,0,sigma[i])
 }

 epsilon<-.01 
 > length(which(abs(mat[1,])>epsilon))/n
 [1] 0.9185
 > length(which(abs(mat[2,])>epsilon))/n
 [1] 0.3168
 > length(which(abs(mat[3,])>epsilon))/n
 [1] 0
 > length(which(abs(mat[4,])>epsilon))/n
 [1] 0
 > length(which(abs(mat[5,])>epsilon))/n
 [1] 0
```

if you look at density of normal, at point $x=\mu$

$$f(\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}$$ by  $\sigma \rightarrow 0^+$

$$f(\mu) \rightarrow \infty$$. on the other hand density at point $x=\mu$ is infinity . Other point be zero

```
  dnorm(0,0,0)
  [1] Inf
  > dnorm(1,0,0)
  [1] 0
```

at last note $\sigma^2$ can not be zero!since $f(x)$ is not defined at $\sigma^2=0$. just we can $\sigma^2 \rightarrow 0^+$.   we can calculate limiting distribution when  $\sigma^2 \rightarrow 0^+$. if $\sigma \rightarrow 0^+$ , the limiting distribution is degenerate distribution , and so it is not normal!. normal is continues and degenerate is discrete. So you have not a normal distribution with zero variance.

Comment: What do you achieve by the last line in the last block of R code? dorm(1,0,0)? Why look at x=1?

Comment: How do you calculate: $$E\left(Y_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}=\sigma^{2}$$

Comment: @Xenusi In that case, I used $dnorm(1,0,0)$ $\mu=0$ $\sigma =0$, I want to show density at any point except $0$ is zero. so I choose one point $1$.

Comment: $E\left(Y_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}=\sigma^{2}$, This is definition of variance ,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition, and in normal distribution mean equals $\mu$ and variance equal $\sigma^2$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution