If $X$ conditional on $f(Y)$ is Normal, then $X$ conditional on $Y$ is Normal?
Consider two real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ with full support. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Assume that
$$
X\mid f(Y)  \sim N(\mu_{f(Y)}, \sigma_{f(Y)})
$$
That is: $X$ conditional on $f(Y)$ has a Normal distribution with mean and variance depending on $f(Y)$.
Question: Does this assumption imply that $X$ given $Y$ has also a Normal distribution? If yes, how are the parameters of this normal distribution related to $\mu_{f(Y)}$ and $\sigma_{f(Y)}$?

$1)$ What is "full" support, the entirety of $\mathbb R?$ $//$ $2)$ What restrictions are there on $f?$ Injective? Surjective? Bijective? Continuous?

I mean support from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ as in the case of the Normal.

Now what about properties of $f?$

I do not impose particular restrictions on $f$ (a part from, perhaps, measurability?). However, if my claim holds under some restrictions of $f$ please let me know

Without additional restrictions on $f$ counterexamples appear to be fairly straightforward to construct

@Glen_b Right. E.g., for $f(y) = |y|,$ let $(X,Y)=(\operatorname{sgn}(Z_2)|Z_1|,\ Z_2)$ where $(Z_1,Z_2)$ is standard bivariate Normal.

If $f$ is constrained to be strictly monotonic, it is pretty easy to see that the statement is correct, otherwise it's false in the general case.

Without the specification of $f$, the conjecture is not true.  A simple counterexample is as follows.

Let $X \sim N(0, 1)$, $Y := X$, and $f(x) \equiv 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ (i.e., $X$) is degenerated, while since $f(Y) \equiv 0$ is a constant, $X$ and $f(Y)$ are independent, whence the conditional distribution of $X$ given $f(Y)$ is the distribution of $X$ itself, which is $N(0, 1)$.
The conjecture is true when $f$ is bijective, under which case $\sigma(Y) = \sigma(f(Y))$.

To circumvent potential dispute as @whuber raised in the comment, here is another slightly more complicated counterexample (but clearly bearing the same idea):

Let $X \sim N(0, 1)$, $Y := |X|$, and $f(x) \equiv 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

In this answer, I carefully derived the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ is given by
\begin{align}
P[X \leq x | Y] = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}I_{[Y \geq -x]}(\omega) & x \leq 0 \\
I_{[Y \leq x]}(\omega) + \frac{1}{2}I_{[Y > x]}(\omega) & x > 0 
\end{cases}, 
\end{align}
which is clearly not a normal distribution (when $Y > 0$, this conditional distribution is a two-point distribution on $-Y$ and $Y$, each with mass $\frac{1}{2}$). On the other hand, for the same reason as the first counterexample, the distribution of $X$ given $f(Y)$ is still $N(0, 1)$.

Although I like simple counterexamples, this one bothers me because an atomic ("degenerated") distribution can be considered a Normal distribution, albeit with zero variance.

@whuber Well, from a rigorous probability perspective, a normal distribution must have a positive scale parameter. Where does you claim "an atomic distribution can be considered as a normal distribution" come from (btw, "atomic distribution" actually has its own definition, which is not the same as "degenerate distribution")?

One definition of a Normal distribution is that its characteristic function has the form $\exp(i\mu t - \sigma^2 t^2/2).$  There's no need to require $\sigma\gt 0$ and doing so just creates unnecessary exceptions.  I'm not going to quibble over the definitions of "atomic" and "degenerate:" what we're discussing satisfies both.

@whuber Just out of my curiosity, can you show me a reputable reference for the characteristic function definition of normal distribution (where it said not requiring $\sigma > 0$)?  I understand that it is not uncommon to meet degenerate multivariate normal distributions, but I have not seen any author who allows $\sigma = 0$ in the definition of a univariate normal distribution.

I'll keep an eye out for this in the near future whenever I consult such references.  In some quick searches online I'm finding self-contradictory definitions. For instance, an account from UT Austin initially requires $\sigma\gt 0$ but later, when generalizing to dimensions $n\ge 1,$ requires only that $\sigma$ be positive semi-definite: and that includes $\sigma=0.$ See p. 8 and see especially problem (3) ($X$ is Gaussian iff $X\cdot t$ is Gaussian for all vectors $t$), which is true only when $\sigma=0$ is acceptable.

The problem assumed $X\mid f(Y) \sim N(\mu_{f(Y)}, \sigma_{f(Y)}).$ The proposed counterexample is $X \sim N(0, 1)$, $Y := X$, and $f(x) \equiv 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. However, if the values of $\mu_y$ and $\sigma_y$ corresponding to every value of $y$ are $\mu_y=0$ and $\mu_y=1$ then that is not a counterexample at all.

Normal with zero variance has been discussed here before https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233834/what-is-the-normal-distribution-when-standard-deviation-is-zero, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455103/one-sample-why-cant-sigma2-0,

The answer is yes. If one is given $Y$ one can evaluate $f$ at $Y,$ i.e. find $f(Y),$ and that determines the distribution. Then given $f(Y),$ one knows that the distribution of $X$ is $\operatorname N(\mu_{f(Y)}, \sigma_{f(Y)}^2).$

How does this answer the question??  Bear in mind that the answer is in the negative: the distribution of $X$ conditional on $f(Y)$ does not necessarily determine the distribution of $X$ conditional on $Y$ (whether or not one restricts the question to Normal distributions).
